# CTRL key is held down in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

Pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> key, it displays the text I want, but the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key remains pressed.
How do I prevent it from being pressed after executing the command?

My *AutoHotKey* code is something like this

```
Ctrl & Numpad7::
SendInput `
(
  some text
  multiline
)
return
```

Comment: Your given code works perfectly for me, with no Ctrl sticking.  Is it possible that this is a Windows Stickykeys issue?  Also, do you get different results if you use `^Numpad7` instead of `Ctrl & Numpad7`?

Comment: With ^ Numpad 7 the same thing keeps happening to me, I do not know if it's because I tried it from my laptop because on another PC it worked for me, maybe it's Windows Stickykeys as you say.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with this something like this :

```
!Crtl Up:: send {Ctrl Down}
```

try this in the end of the script(the line after return).